# SQL: How to calculate %product that each customer buy?

Tags: sql

For example, my shop has 20 products(20 ProductID: COUNT(DISTINCT(ProductID)) and I want to calculate each customer(group by)like this:

```
CUST_CODE  |  %Product Buy
------------------------
CUST1      |  50% (CUST1 buy 10 ProductID of 20 ProductID)
CUST2      |  25% (CUST2 buy 5 ProductID of 20 ProductID)
```

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

It is called SQL EXPRESSIONS.

The idea could looks like:

```
SELECT (A*100/TOTAL) AS PRODUCT_BUY;
```

WHERE A can be a NUMBER:10,5

or a SELECT query inside of a SELECT query, for an example:

`SELECT SKU_AMOUNT FROM SKU.TB WHERE CUSTID = CUST1`

Further, if we develop this idea, we need to look to the side of `JOIN` as well.

Probably it will be better to see how tables looks like for formulating an exact final query.